# Login failure when running a SSIS package from a SQL Server job

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, jobs

I have a SSIS package that migrates data from a Sybase database to SQL Server. The connection to the source database has been made through an ODBC connection.

If I run the package directly on my machine, it runs successfully, however if I want to run it through a SQL Server job I have created on my local machine (where the destination database is), I'm getting a login failure error:

```
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login failed for user 'xxx\user1'.".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot open database "MySybaseDatabase" requested by the login.
```

I know that the job runs as 'SQL Server Agent Service Account' that is in fact `xxx\user1`
 and it is different from a user has been set up in ODBC connection to access the source database, but don't know why the odbc connection login does not take the precedance and is used rather than the agent service account?

I read some posts in different sites, they were talking about setting up proxy, etc, but don't know if it is quite relevant to my issue.

The connection to the source database has been set up via ODBC, but as the step was failing, I added the userId and password to it to force SQL uses the userId I want rather than SQL Sever agant user, but it didn't help.
[image]
Do you know how we can fix this login issue?

Thank you.

Comment: In your sybase connection manager, what is the connection string property look like? Are you applying a configuration to it?

Comment: Yes, it is done in ODBC connection, and the test connection can be established successfully there, but I know know how force SQL Server job use that credential, e.g: userId = dba not the SQL server Agent user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem while importing data from an Excel file using SSIS packages. I found [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/runeetv/ssis-package-using-sql-authentication-and-dontsavesensitive-as-protectionlevel) and solved the problem.

**EDIT**: Important steps: 
1 - When saving the SSIS package to the file system, select the "**Package protection level**" to "**Do not save sensitive data**".

Then, follow these steps:
1 - Open the SSIS package in Visual Studio 
2 - Select **SSIS** -> **Package Configurations**
3 - On the **Package Configurations Organizer** click **Add**
4 - On the window that'll open click **Next** 
5 - Set the configuration type to **XML configuration file**
6 - On the **Configuration file name** click **Browse**, select the folder in which you want to store the configuration file, choose a name to this file and then hit **Save**
7 - When you're done here, click **Next**
8 - Choose the right **connection manager** and click on the **+** sign to expand it, then expand **Properties** and check the checkbox correspondent to **Password**. Then click **Next**.
9 - Choose a name to your configuration file and click **Finish**.

The following XML configuration file will be created on the location you specified previously (*here I'm using the code from the tutorial as an example*):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<DTSConfiguration>

      <DTSConfigurationHeading>

            <DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="Domain\UserName" GeneratedFromPackageName="Package" GeneratedFromPackageID="{77FB98FB-E1AF-48D9-8A43-9FD6B1790837}" GeneratedDate="22-12-2009 16:12:59"/>

      </DTSConfigurationHeading>

      <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[runeet2k8.sa].Properties[Password]" ValueType="String">

                  <ConfiguredValue></ConfiguredValue>

      </Configuration>

</DTSConfiguration>
```

The only thing you'll have to do here is edit the XML file and change this: 
`<ConfiguredValue></ConfiguredValue>`
into this:
`<ConfiguredValue>YourPasswordGoesHere</ConfiguredValue>`

Then save the package.

When creating your SQL job, don't forget to add the configuration file to the job in the tab **Configurations**.

Comment: @dezso I've edited the answer in order to contain all the major steps I followed to solve the problem.